# Model validation not run when using EntriesService saveEntry method

Tags: plugin-development, entries, entrymodel, validation, saveentry

Currently i have to validate my model before saving because of some custom validation rules setted on the model which won't run when using the EntriesService saveEntry method.

This causes a two step validation when errors arise, first you get the custom validation errors and after that if there is still something wrong you get the "base" validation errors.

Is this a normal behavior?

```
$model->validate();
```

After that i am saving the model like so:

```
$result = craft()->entries->saveEntry($model);
```

Custom rules on model:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = parent::rules();
    $rules[] = ['state', 'validateState'];
    $rules[] = ['vacancyId', 'validateId'];
    //$rules[] = ['vacancyId', 'numerical', 'unique' => false];
    $rules[] = ['office', 'validateOffice'];
    $rules[] = ['sector', 'validateSector'];

    return $rules;
}
```

Why are the custom validation rules not evaluated on the saveEntry method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behavior... `EntriesService->saveEntry()` never calls `validate()` on the model directly, but does call `validate()` on the `EntryRecord` and if there are errors, add it back to the model and return.

So if you want to run custom validation rules before calling `saveEntry` you'll need to do that yourself and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Brad, so there is no way to combine those two validations. Overruling rules with defaults Craft or Yii validators like the one commented out (which i can't get to work), are these validated on the EntryRecord method then or still separately? Thanks in clearing things up!

Comment: They would be validated on the EntryRecord if that was the class you were extending.